# How can I run c++ program with .txt file as an arguement on mac terminal?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, g++

I am trying to run a c++ program with a txt file as a command line arguement. I used chmod u+rwx filename to change the access and g++ to compile and ./ to run. I am keep getting an error message saying "zsh: permission denied: ./
". I can make unix executable file using g++, bu when I run the progrma with ./ and txt file ans an arguement, it returns an error message above.
what my terminal looks like

```
-Air ~ % cd /Users/klee/Desktop/pa3+ect/cs1/page-link            
-Air page-link % g++ page.cpp page_rank.cpp web.cpp -o rank1
-Air page-link % ./ rank1
zsh: permission denied: ./
-Air page-link %
```

Comment: Can you compile and execute a HelloWorld?

Comment: This probably is not a C++ question.

Comment: Please include what exactly your command is, and the exact error message. `./` should neither do anything nor cause any problems.

Comment: I can execute hello world. If I use g++ helloworld.cpp it creates executable unix fiel, and if I click on it it runs. However if I try to run it with ./ on terminal, it doesn't. This is what I got on my terminal.

Comment: -Air ~ % cd /Users/klee/Desktop/pa3+ect/cs1/page-link            
-Air page-link % g++ page.cpp page_rank.cpp web.cpp -o rank1
-Air page-link % ./ rank1
zsh: permission denied: ./
-Air page-link %

Comment: It looks like you have extra whitespace where there should not be any.  See the difference between these command lines `./  rank1` (error) and `./rank1` (ok!!!)  Then you will use whitespace AFTER the command name and before the name of the text file you want it to process.

Answer (score 0):

U can use the standard argument to get the file path and then parse the file text into a variable.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
cout << "You have entered " << argc 
     << " arguments:" << "\n"; 

for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) 
    cout << argv[i] << "\n"; 

return 0; 
}
```